# Classification of groups of order $56$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

The particular problem that I am facing is that when $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $7$ and $K$ is a subgroup of order $8$ .Now,  we can consider the map $\theta :K \to Aut(H)$ we see that $\theta(k) \to khk^{-1}$ and $khk^{-1}=h^{-1}$.

I am unable to proceed after this .I need to prove that :

$a)$ when $K$ is isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ there is only one group which is non Abelian.

$(b) $ when $K = Z_4 \times Z_2$ there are two non isomorphic  groups.

$(c) $ when $K=Z_8$ there is only one group

Comment: What about the case "$K$ is non-Abelian"?

Comment: I would try to do that on my own if someone helps me out in these 3 cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\rm Aut}(H) \cong C_6$ is cyclic of order $6$. So in all cases, the non-trivial homomorphisms $\theta$ all have image of order $2$ and kernel $L$ of order $4$.

So you just need to find the normal subgroups $L$ of $K$ of order $4$, and then determine which of these give rise to isomorphic groups $H \ltimes K$.

In Case a), we have $L \cong C_2 \times C_2$, and all such $K$ give rise to isomorphic groups $H \ltimes K$ (note that all such $L$ are equivalent under ${\rm Aut}(K)$).

In Case b), we can have $L \cong C_4$ or $L \cong C_2^2$. The $C_2^2$ is unique. There are two copies of $C_4$, but they give isomorphic $H \ltimes K$.

In Case c) we must have $L=C_4$.

Comment: In the case where $K \cong D_8$ I am getting the kernel as $4$ so either it's a Klein four group or a cyclic group. Then there are two possible semi direct product. In my book it is mentioned that there should be three isomorphic non abelian groups

Comment: And, when $ K \cong Q_8$ then kernel of the map should be   $\{i, -i, 1,-1\}$ , $\{j, -j, 1,-1\}$  ,$\{k, -k, 1,-1\}$ .So the semi direct groups are isomorphic if their kernels are isomorphic. So shouldn't there be just one map? In my book it is mentioned two

Comment: You are correct, there are two nonisomorphic nonabelian groups with $K \cong D_8$, and one with $K \cong Q_8$. There is also one abelian group in each case corresponding to the trivial map $\thete$.